# Oracle forms 10g, running a form

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I have been facing trouble with running oracle 10g forms, I tried everything I know but it did not work. So please help me.

My computer specifications:

- OS: windows xp service pack 2.
- Internet browser: Mozilla Firefox 3.6 RC 2.
- Database: Oracle 10g 10.2.0.
- Oracle developer suite 10g.
- JInitiator 1.3.1.30.
- jre-6u18-windows-i586.

The problem: I start oc4j then I start oracle forms designer, then I made a form that suppose to display the employees table, the Firefox browser start and display a white empty page, when I tried to use Microsoft Internet Explorer, it did not work also, and the browser closed and display it's error message.

I hope there will be someone to help me find out what is the reason because I am really confused.

Comment: What address is displayed in the Firefox address bar? What error do you get in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like your browser does not find your java plugin in your browser.
Here you can find out if you have java plugin installed: http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp

In your `formsweb.cfg` file you can tell which java plugin version to use. Add to your `[application]` section some line like:

```
jpi_mimetype=application/x-java-applet
```

or (which is not as flexible and ignored by IE):

```
jpi_mimetype=application/x-java-applet;jpi-version=1.6.0_18
```

Another ideas:

- Your `FORMS_PATH` variable is not correct
- Your `FORMS`  variable  is not correct
- Your `CLASSSPATH` variable is not correct